# grafana alert with "{}=1.7976931348623157e+308"

Tags: alert, prometheus, grafana

grafana

[image]

datasource: prometheus

As you can see from  the pic, the latency is not greater than the alert threshold. But I got plenty of alerts as above at night.

what does this alert mean and how to resolve it.
Any idea will be appreciate.